# Using a final class for string constants

Tags: java, constants

I want to use something like `Setting.RES_WIDTH` in my code without the need for a getter function (i.e.: custom getter, enum's `.name()`, `.toString()` or `.valueOf()`).

Someone suggested using a final class, so I wrote this:

```
public final class Setting {

    public final static String RES_WIDTH        = "resolution_width";
    public final static String RES_HEIGHT       = "resolution_height";
    public final static String FULLSCREEN       = "fullscreen_enabled";
    public final static String VSYNC            = "vsync_enabled";

    //Prevent someone from creating an instance of this class
    private Setting() {}
}
```

This code works, but I am wondering if there are any kind of issues (performance, GC, etc) that might arise from using this.

Comment: Seems to me like you worry to much. Have you heard the saying about premature optimization?

Comment: I haven't, I'll look it up. But yes, that's quite possible, even with websites I worry a lot about optimizing my code the best way possible, even if it probably only makes 1 cpu-cycle of difference haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be any GC overhead since there won't be any instantiated instances to collect.

I think there's a small overhead by accessing a class' static field rather than an in-scope variable ; however, I would consider it largely worth the improved readability/maintainability.

I guess you could also argue you'll use up a little bit more of your permGen / Meta space, but I've never heard it be a consequent problem.